missing xaxis ticks with plotly
I have a pandas dataframe with hourly data shown in 7 subplots for a weeks data.
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=7,
    cols=1,
    subplot_titles=subPlotNames,
    shared_xaxes=True,
    shared_yaxes='all'
)

My x-axis shows ticks at 0, 5, 10, 15, and 20 hours at the bottom of the page.
I have added the following update_layout statement to get hourly ticks:
fig.update_layout(
    barmode = 'group',
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='linear',
        tick0=0,
        dtick=23,
        tickvals=np.arange(0, 23, 1),
        ticktext = [f"{i}u" for i in np.arange(0, 23, 1)]
    )
)

However, the statement does not add the x-ticks in the graph. How can I add the ticks on the x-axis?
I am running python 3.13 with dash 2.18.2 and plotly 5.24.1 on an ubuntu 24.10 machine.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Can you show us what the output currently looks like, and maybe share an example df/variable names for reproducibility?
